# Problem with crosswords

Tags: formatting, color

While making a crosswords in LaTeX, I found out I am unable to do two things:

1. A part of it must be blue.
2. Two letters must be visible in the unsolved version.

Can anybody tell me how to do these two things?

*edit: I am so sorry for writing "crossroads" at first. I must have been tired or something, so I mistook crossroads for crosswords :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have to be honest: I have no idea at all what you are talking about. I do know what a crossroad is but I've never heard of anybody making one in LaTeX. Also, I doubt your question is really pdfTeX-specific. Although it is hard to be sure since I don't know what your question is. Hence I don't want to retag your question as I have no idea what tags might be more suitable, but do consider this when editing your question.

Comment: Are you talking about cross*words*?

Comment: do you mean somethinng like this https://www.crosswordclub.co.uk/demo/printable/EXAMPLE1/print_solution/3

Comment: Are you using the `cwpuzzle` package?  If so, post an example of a small puzzle using it and then describe what you need with respect to that. Your second question makes sense to me, but it's not obvious what you want in the first.)

Answer (score 10):

The `cwpuzzle` package is amazingly flexible in the kinds of things you can do, so I'm posting an answer that I think answers your question.

The package allows you to specify the formatting of any particular cell in the puzzle, and also allows you to define coloured cells.  Here's a puzzle created for the season with three additions: First, I've created a macro to make numbering the cells easier. Second, and as the answers to your questions: (1) I've  defined two coloured cell types (`R` and `G`) and coloured two of the important words using that cell type. (2) For two of the cells, I've specified the `[Sf]` cell type which means that the cell will appear "as is" with a frame.  Options (1) and (2) can be combined as I've done in the example, by adding a colour specification to an `S` formatted cell.

Have fun solving the puzzle...

(Please edit your question to be clearer if this doesn't answer it correctly.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cwpuzzle}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcounter{clue}
\newcommand{\cl}{\stepcounter{clue}\theclue}
\PuzzleDefineColorCell{R}{Crimson}
\PuzzleDefineColorCell{G}{Green!80}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries A Crossword Puzzle for the Season
\end{center}
\begin{Puzzle}{11}{1}
|[\cl]D |R  |E  |A  |[\cl][Gf]M |*  |[\cl]W  |* |[\cl]E |[\cl]Y |[\cl]E |.
|*  |*  |*  |*  |[][Gf]E |* |I  |*  |[\cl]N |E  |W  |.
|*  |*  |[\cl][Rf]C |[\cl][Rf]H |[][Gf]R |[][Rf]I |[][Rf]S |[][Rf]T |[][Rf]M |[][Rf]A |[][Rf]S  |.
|*  |*  |[\cl]O |A  |[][Gf]R    |*  |H      |*  |[\cl]I     |R  |*  |.
|[\cl]H |A  |P  |P  |[][Gf]Y    |*  |E      |*  |T      |*  |*  |.
|*      |*  |*  |P  |*  |*  |[\cl]S     |[\cl][RSf]O |Y      |*  |*  |.
|[\cl]P     |R  |A  |Y  |*  |*  |*      |[][GSf]F    |*      |*  |*  |.
\end{Puzzle}

\vspace{1.5in}
\begin{PuzzleClues}{\bfseries Across}
% Normally the word of the clue is put in the second argument of the \Clue macro
% But that spoils the fun for solving it, and it can be left blank
\Clue{1}{}{The impossible from \emph{Man of La Mancha}.}
\Clue{4}{}{007 in \emph{Golden\ldots}}
\Clue{7}{}{Define counter, command, length, etc.}
\Clue{8}{}{This puzzle posted on this eve.}
\Clue{10}{}{Stick one of these in even when people don’t want you to.}
\Clue{11}{}{Opposite end of ultraviolet \emph{abbr.}}
\Clue{13}{}{Vegans would prefer a turkey made of this.}
\Clue{15}{}{You might do this at midnight Mass}
\end{PuzzleClues}
\begin{PuzzleClues}{\bfseries Down}
\Clue{2}{}{We wish you a (8 across).}
\Clue{3}{}{Best for the new year.}
\Clue{4}{}{Not a good feeling for the season.}
\Clue{5}{}{(9 down) New \ldots}
\Clue{6}{}{Vegans’ response to the real turkey.}
\Clue{8}{}{Bobby in America.}
\Clue{9}{}{\ldots New (5 down).}
\Clue{14}{}{Steinbeck’s \emph{Mice and Men} is missing this.}
\end{PuzzleClues}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Can I buy a vowel? `:)` Great answer, Alan!

Comment: Thank you Alan, this helped me a lot. But I have one more problem, I actually need one cell to be coloured and also have a letter written in it. I tried |[][Gf][Sf]F, but that does not work. What should I write to make your "F"-cell green?

Comment: @Lucy Sorry I forgot to add that option to the puzzle. You can combine the cell type specifications, so to make the F cell green just use `[][GSf]F` as the cell specification.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I dont know what I would do if it wasnt for you :) One more question. My clues are in two columns that are one under the other (in the pdf version). I want to have them next to each other, like you. How can I do that?

Comment: @Lucy To get the clues side-by-side just make sure there's no  blank line between the two `PuzzleClues` environments. If you want separation to make your code more readable just use a commented blank line.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you again, Alan, I didnt even hope for so much help :) Have a great day :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I have a question, how did the clues section acomodate automaticly in two separated columns?

Comment: @Cragfelt This is done automatically by the `cwpuzzle` package: the `PuzzleClues` environment is a `minipage` set to `.45\textwidth`. As long as there's no space or blank line between the across and down clue groups they will appear side by side.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMunn! But somehow, it did not set in two separate columns even when I take off the blank space between across and down. It displayed in just one column and paragraph. In fact, I had to put the clue groups by using multicols and minipage environments by myself. Here is my example https://github.com/Cragfelt/MathTeachingWorks/blob/master/crucifunc.tex

Comment: @Cragfelt You are using the `unboxed` package option which removes the `minipage` environment from the `PuzzleClues`.